# Mobile Facebook hacked via wireless router

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, router

I Wanna ask a general question..

I have used my mobile Facebook chat in the company.  I used the wireless router in the company to access the net..

My question : is there any way that the administrator can read the chat on my phone.  Can he hacked it.  Or the Facebook chat  is so secured...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It's an software algorithm sir.  Look exactly Wat the answer will be

Comment: Yes, let's see if that makes sense to anyone ... :-)

Comment: Simple solution, get off Facebook chat and get back to work!

Comment: I did this chat in the break. But the administrator is so bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facebook chat most likely uses an open HTTP connection to communicate your traffic in clear text unencrypted. That means that the administrator (or anyone in the network skilled enough) *in theory* can monitor the text transferred. However the traffic going in and out is most probably tremendous so it requires that this person is REALLY interested in the traffic you are sending and filtering out exactly your traffic or searching for specific keywords targeted for this. The password is most probably transferred encrypted though (HTTPS or similar).

So, the conclusion is that it is theoretically possible for them to monitor your traffic although mostly unlikely. Unless you have committed a crime, or are suspected of something considerably illoyal I would say that the risk is very low. I would say it is very unusual unless you work in a company with very strict policies against facebook usage or similar situation.

If you see signs of info leakage I would rather suspect that you do not have protected your facebook account with the right permissions so that they can see your texts or someone who can see the text has leaked it to them.

I would generally recommend you to not publish anything on facebook that you cannot stand by if confronted by an employer, friend or collegue. Facebook is by nature intented for spreading information, not keeping secrets.